# Unable to get the value of Enum from asp-route-data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I have an enum:

```cs
public enum mediaType
{        
    Video = 0,
    Voice = 1,
    Image = 2
}
```

Now I want to pass a value from view to controller by using Tag Helper.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="ShowMedia" asp-action="Index" asp-route-typeindex="mediaType.Video">All Video</a>
```

and in Controller

```cs
public IActionResult Index(mediaType typeindex=mediaType.Image)
{
    //does something
    return View(typeindex.ToString(), model);
}
```

The problem is that `typeindex` parameter is always filled with its default value: `mediaType.Image` and it never gets the value for `asp-route-typeindex="mediaType.Video"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the HTML element, you would see you are passing a string "mediaType.Video" but not an Enum value.

[image]

In the controller, the `Index` will use the default value `mediaType.Image`

You need a `@` syntax to use the variable/value which is from Razor.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="ShowMedia" asp-action="Index" 
    asp-route-typeindex="@mediaType.Video">All Video</a>
```

[image]

---

Aside, would suggest naming `mediaType` with Pascal case for the [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#naming-conventions).

```
public enum MediaType
{        
    Video = 0,
    Voice = 1,
    Image = 2
}
```